How to apply Azure App Configuration only when both labels match?
I have a production environment located in the westus region. I want to set a configuration that only applies when both the prod environment and the westus region are matched.
Currently, the label filter overwrites the configuration if any of the labels match. For example, if I set the configuration with the following code, the config will apply to all prod environments and all westus regions, but I want the config to only apply to an environment that matches both labels (prod and westus).
Requirement:
I need the configuration to apply only when both prod and westus labels are matched, not when either of them matches.
Example:

Test:Test = true
matches all environments
Test:Test = true prod
matches all prod environments
Test:Test = true westus
matches all westus regions
Test:Test = true prod, westus
should match only when both prod environment and westus region are present

Question: How can I modify the label filtering logic so that the configuration is applied only when both labels (prod and westus) are matched, instead of when any one of them matches?

You could create a new label prod/westus and use it to override any existing settings. For example:
Key: Test:Test Label: prod/westus
ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(...)
        .Select("Test:*", $"{env}") // e.g., prod, staging, etc.
        .Select("Test:*", $"{env}/" + $"{region}"); // e.g., prod/westus
});

Alternatively, use region as a prefix of the key name instead of a label. Create a key-value:
Key: westus:Test:Test Label: prod
Then in your code, you load settings for that region and then trim the region name from the key. For example:
ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(...)
        .Select("Test:*", $"{env}")
        .Select($"{region}:Test:*", $"{env}")
        .TrimKeyPrefix($"{region}:");
});

